# What types of validations are automatically handled by Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Lets say I have a model defined as follows:

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator, RegexValidator

alphanumeric_validator = RegexValidator(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')

class Person(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, validators=[alphanumeric_validator])
    number = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    email = models.EmailField()
```

Now, lets say I am serializing and creating Person objects using Django Rest Framework. It looks like like this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Person
from rest_framework.response import Response

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name', 'number', 'email')

class PostPerson(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = PersonSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()=
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Now, my question is this: when I am validating the serializer using `is_valid()`, does DRF handle the `validators=[alphanumeric_validator]`, and `validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)]`? Also, I am sure DRF automatically handles the `max_length` property, but does it also check if the `email` is an actual email address using the proper regex?

I am generally just confused about clean, full_clean, and all the methods that are called during form validations and serializer validations, so would like to get some solid explanations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django rest framework validation behaves similarly to Django `ModelForm` validation; it takes the arguments from your models fields and validates accordingly.

For example we'll take a simple model & serializer class that has a field with a uniqueness constraint.

```
class CustomerReportRecord(models.Model):
    time_raised = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    reference = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)


class CustomerReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerReportRecord
```

and when we open up Django shell we can see that the validator has been applied to the serializer (notice the `max_length` and the `validators` list)

```
>>> from project.example.serializers import CustomerReportSerializer
>>> serializer = CustomerReportSerializer()
>>> print(repr(serializer))
CustomerReportSerializer():
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    time_raised = DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    reference = CharField(max_length=20, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=CustomerReportRecord.objects.all())>])
```

Printing the `repr` of a serializer instance will show you exactly what validation rules it applies. There's no extra hidden validation behaviour being called on the model instance.

When it comes to the `.clean` and `.full_clean` methods just another way to validate user input data — normalise it to a consistent format. These are executed in Django forms when you call the `.is_valid()` method on a **form**, not in your rest framework serializer.

Back to REST framework validators though. Lets take a look at the `Serializer.to_internal_value` method.

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    """
    Dict of native values <- Dict of primitive datatypes.
    """
    if not isinstance(data, dict):
        message = self.error_messages['invalid'].format(
            datatype=type(data).__name__
        )
        raise ValidationError({
            api_settings.NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY: [message]
        })

    ret = OrderedDict()
    errors = OrderedDict()
    fields = self._writable_fields

    for field in fields:
        validate_method = getattr(self, 'validate_' + field.field_name, None)
        primitive_value = field.get_value(data)
        try:
            validated_value = field.run_validation(primitive_value)
            if validate_method is not None:
                validated_value = validate_method(validated_value)
        except ValidationError as exc:
            errors[field.field_name] = exc.detail
        except DjangoValidationError as exc:
            errors[field.field_name] = list(exc.messages)
        except SkipField:
            pass
        else:
            set_value(ret, field.source_attrs, validated_value)

    if errors:
        raise ValidationError(errors)

    return ret
```

We can see here that the serializer invokes `field.run_validation` method, which uses model field validators and they raise a `DjangoValidationError` if validation fails. If it succeeds it'll continue to run any additional validators that are present such as serializer field specific validators (`.validate_<field_name>`).

Read up more on validation and how it works in Django & DRF here:

1. [Form Field Validation Django 2.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)
2. [Validators - DRF Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/)
3. [Serializer Validation - DRF Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)
4. [Correct way to validate Django Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036315/correct-way-to-validate-django-model-objects)
5. [DRF Serializer code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L468)

Hope this helps to understand how validation works in DRF if even by a bit

EDIT: As long as your field that you're storing emails in is defined to be an `EmailField` in your models then DRF will validate emails. More on that can be found [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#emailfield)