# django: is it safe to remove `blank=True` from web-service only app?

Tags: python, django

I'm starting a project using an existing db. The models generated from `inspectdb` have

```
(...null=True, blank=True)
```

in various fields. The documentation mentions that the `blank` argument is related to django forms. I'm making a web service project, using *django rest framework* and the django ORM. Absolutely no *view* component (autogenerated forms, html templates, etc) of the MVC.

Does that mean it's safe to remove `blank=True` from my models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `blank=True` your application will fail validation when trying to serialize data with blank fields. Django rest framework `ModelSerializer` enforces any kind of validation that is on the model fields. It works similarly to Django `ModelForms`.

If you're not using `ModelSerializers` and try to save a blank value against a field without `blank=True` your save method will throw an exception instead.

TL;DR: if you remove `blank=True` your DRF serializer will fail validation against empty fields.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198360/what-types-of-validations-are-automatically-handled-by-django-rest-framework) question on how validation works in DRF.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.

Whatever your service is, you probably want to validate data. And Django's validation relies on that `blank=True`. It's not just for forms and templates. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#blank):

> `blank` is validation-related.

Answer (score 1):

Django Rest Framework will use the `blank` attribute on a model field in serializer validation. When `blank` is `False`, which is the default value, the ModelSerializer will raise a ValidationError if a value is not set for this field in a POST request.

Basically, if you remove `blank=True` from a field and try to create a record with no value for that field, you will get a 400 response from your server.

Nothing will break, just this request will fail to create a resource. In my book I'd call that safe. It really just comes down to whether you want the field to be required or not. But since you have `null=True`, it seems reasonable to have `blank=True`.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old, but I came looking for answer so adding it after my experiments, may be helpful for someone in 2024

- django==4.2.11
- djangorestframework==3.15.0
- python==3.8.9

This does not seem to be correct in my current code.

I have a model with following attributes

```
class TestModels(models.Model):
    boolean_field = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=False)
    integer_field = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
    char_field = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Now I added a serializer which looks like follows

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.TestModels
        fields = "__all__"
```

and following is my API view

```
class TestModelView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.TestModels.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TestSerializer
```

simple django app nothing complicated,
but to my surprise `blank=False` (which is default) but I added here for visibility purpose.

This successfully pass the validation and save the NULL data in database.

On the other hand Django admin validates it, so boolean_field and integer_field is required, it raise the validation error.

However the django docs still seems to say the same regarding null vs blank whatever it was written in django 2.2 docs
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/

> For both string-based and non-string-based fields, you will also need to set blank=True if you wish to permit empty values in **forms**, as the null parameter only affects database storage

It explicitly mentions "forms" it might be that which does not include djangorestframework ModelSerializer

I looked up the drf validations [drf-validators](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/)
and printed the `repr()` function on my serializer which printed the following value.

```
 >>repr(m_serializer)
TestSerializer():\n    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)\n    boolean_field = BooleanField(allow_null=True, required=False)\n    integer_field = IntegerField(allow_null=True, required=False)\n    char_field = CharField(max_length=200)
```

from above I can see that `required=False`

Hence if you remove `blank=True` then it only do validation on admin panel or django forms, drf serializer seems to ignore that whether it's True or False